# adding svg as background in css

Tags: css, svg, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add an svg as background for a div.

This is the SVG.

```html
<svg version="1.1" class="h-4 text-dark"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52.966 52.966;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M51.704,51.273L36.845,35.82c3.79-3.801,6.138-9.041,6.138-14.82c0-11.58-9.42-21-21-21s-21,9.42-21,21s9.42,21,21,21
    c5.083,0,9.748-1.817,13.384-4.832l14.895,15.491c0.196,0.205,0.458,0.307,0.721,0.307c0.25,0,0.499-0.093,0.693-0.279
    C52.074,52.304,52.086,51.671,51.704,51.273z M21.983,40c-10.477,0-19-8.523-19-19s8.523-19,19-19s19,8.523,19,19
    S32.459,40,21.983,40z"/>
</svg>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.logo {
    background: url("white_logo.svg") no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.menu {
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #ff8c00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* touch-action: none; */
    /* user-select: none; */
}

.parent {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 214748364;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and this is how I have my htlm set up:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="logo"></div>
    <div>
<div>
```

I tried different SVGs and still does not work (if I view the svg in the browser I see it fine).
If I put and url of a picture it works.
If I put a bg of logo to black I see a black square with no svg inside.
I tried converting the svg to png and still nothing.

**EDIT**

This code is part of an extension and is injected on a webpage

Answer (score 1):

SVG rendering issues were due to a bug in the viewBox
This is what your SVG looks like when loaded into a vector editor.

[image]

Using the JS method `getBBox()` we find out the required values of the viewBox parameters at which the SVG shape will be completely placed on the SVG canvas

```html
<svg version="1.1" class="h-4 text-dark"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52.966 52.966;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="p1" d="M51.704,51.273L36.845,35.82c3.79-3.801,6.138-9.041,6.138-14.82c0-11.58-9.42-21-21-21s-21,9.42-21,21s9.42,21,21,21
    c5.083,0,9.748-1.817,13.384-4.832l14.895,15.491c0.196,0.205,0.458,0.307,0.721,0.307c0.25,0,0.499-0.093,0.693-0.279
    C52.074,52.304,52.086,51.671,51.704,51.273z M21.983,40c-10.477,0-19-8.523-19-19s8.523-19,19-19s19,8.523,19,19
    S32.459,40,21.983,40z"/>
</svg>

<script>
console.log(p1.getBBox());
</script>
```

instead of `viewBox ="0 0 20 20"` set `viewBox ="0.98 0 51 52.96"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" class="h-4 text-dark"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="30" height="30"
     viewBox="0.98 0 51 52.96" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <path d="M51.704,51.273L36.845,35.82c3.79-3.801,6.138-9.041,6.138-14.82c0-11.58-9.42-21-21-21s-21,9.42-21,21s9.42,21,21,21
    c5.083,0,9.748-1.817,13.384-4.832l14.895,15.491c0.196,0.205,0.458,0.307,0.721,0.307c0.25,0,0.499-0.093,0.693-0.279
    C52.074,52.304,52.086,51.671,51.704,51.273z M21.983,40c-10.477,0-19-8.523-19-19s8.523-19,19-19s19,8.523,19,19
    S32.459,40,21.983,40z"/>
</svg>
```

Red border shows SVG canvas borders.    red border is only needed for demonstration. Before encoding SVG in `background` it needs to be removed from styles

To place the svg code in the background CSS, it needs to be encoded in **[URL-encoder for SVG](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/)**

***Below is the complete code with your layout***

```css
.logo {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' class='h-4 text-dark' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0.98 0 51 52.96'%3E%3Cpath d='M51.704,51.273L36.845,35.82c3.79-3.801,6.138-9.041,6.138-14.82c0-11.58-9.42-21-21-21s-21,9.42-21,21s9.42,21,21,21 c5.083,0,9.748-1.817,13.384-4.832l14.895,15.491c0.196,0.205,0.458,0.307,0.721,0.307c0.25,0,0.499-0.093,0.693-0.279 C52.074,52.304,52.086,51.671,51.704,51.273z M21.983,40c-10.477,0-19-8.523-19-19s8.523-19,19-19s19,8.523,19,19 S32.459,40,21.983,40z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.menu {
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #ff8c00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* touch-action: none; */
    /* user-select: none; */
}

.parent {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 214748364;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="menu">
<div class="logo">

</div> 
    <div>
<div>
```

Comment: @Stefano Pozzi If my answer was helpful to you, please do not forget to mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `background-image` instead of `background` like this:

```css
.logo {
    background-image: url("white_logo.svg"); /* delete no-repeat */
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Bella li ✌

Comment: Parent element - relative

Comment: `<div class="parent">` has a `position: fixed` so it's `relative` for all the child elements by default...

Comment: using `background-image` unfortunately does not fix it :/

Comment: Mmm .. try to add `background-color: #fff` to `.logo`

Comment: `background-image` does not understand `no-repeat`. Try only `background-image: url("white_logo.svg")`

Comment: @dariowskii adding `#fff` only makes the div white

Comment: @Pof yes that was the problem!

Comment: @Pof ty, solved the issue I had of it not showing when inspecting the page. But the svg still not showing :(

Comment: @Pof sadly it did not

Comment: does the fact that this code is supposed to be injected in a webpage change anything?